# simple Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I'm quite new to Perl and now are seeking help to parse a simple line of code.

what I need to parse is in the from of

```
#include "filename"
```

I just need the regular expression to get the file name.

I know there's split method in Python that do this, don't know if there's similar 
func in Perl

Thanks

Comment: FYI: *many* things are coming from Perl to Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do this with `split` in Perl:

```
my $fn = (split('"', $include_line))[1];
```

...but that's a pretty obtuse way of going about it.  I'd opt for

```
my ($fn) = $line =~ /^#include +"([^"]+)"/;
```

instead, which is clearer and also has the advantage of returning nothing on non-`#include` lines rather than returning false positives if your input file contains any other lines with double-quoted text.

Answer (score 5):

```
my ($fn) = $include =~ /"([^"]*)"/;
```

or

```
my ($fn) = $include =~ /^\s*#\s*include\s*"([^"]*)"/;
```

Comment: maybe somekind of substr with index? ;)

Comment: @loldop why would you resort to [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) and [index](http://p3rl.org/index)? Especially since `/^\s*#\s*include\s*"([^"]*)"/` is faster, easier to understand, and more robust.

Comment: @BradGilbert just for another 'or', not insist on it.

Comment: @loldop, The two versions I posted are both better than the other for different reasons. It's not supposed to be an exhaustive list. Listing a solution that has no benefit just for the sake of listing it is silly. That said, index/check/index/check/substr might be a faster alternative to my first solution (though far far less readable).

Comment: @loldop I went ahead and tested it; a rudimentary [`substr`](http://p3rl.org/substr) and [`index`](http://p3rl.org/index) version is **slower** than the regex version. (one roughly the same as `/.*#.*include.*"([^"]*)".*/`) If you made it so that there couldn't be anything between `#` and `include`, it would almost be as fast as the correct regex version. (tested multiple times with [`dumbbench`](http://p3rl.org/Dumbbench))

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, I would have thought it a replacement for `/"([^"]*)"/`

Comment: `/"([^"]*)"/` and it's substr/index version are roughly equal; though the substr/index version has a slight edge.

Answer (score 1):

If what you really need is to extract headers from a bunch of c/c++ files, you can use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) to do it easily:

```
ack --cc '#include "([^"]+)' -h --output=\$1  | sort | uniq
```